# Error Illegal length modifier specified 'f' in s[np]printf Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have the following error in laravel, it is intermittent

```
local.ERROR: Illegal length modifier specified 'f' in s[np]printf call {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 1): Illegal length modifier specified 'f' in s[np]printf call at /home/usuario/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:122)
[stacktrace]
#0 {main}
```

The error I receive only in my hosting in localhost everything is fine.

Trying to resolve this error I go to the file that says the exception `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:122`

And I see this Code:

```
/**
     * Write the contents of a file.
     *
     * @param  string  $path
     * @param  string  $contents
     * @param  bool  $lock
     * @return int|bool
     */
    public function put($path, $contents, $lock = false)
    {
        return file_put_contents($path, $contents, $lock ? LOCK_EX : 0);
    }
```

Said function is from laravel but I don't see any problem in it.

I have PHP 7.4 hosting and I use the version of laravel 5.8 in this project

How could I solve it?

I already did all the steps of

```
php artisan clear;  
php artisan view:clear;  
php artisan config:cache;
```

Nothing works. Anyone have any idea why this happens ???

Grades:

I updated my version of laravel from 5.8 to version 6.0 without any success the problem persists, I don't know why it does it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete vendor folder then run `composer install`

Comment: I did a composer install and composer update before and it has not worked the problem continues to appear, do you have any idea that it generates this error?

Comment: But did you delete vendor folder before composer install ?

Comment: How do I remove it? is it a shared server!

Comment: The issue actually I belive is your laravel version is too old for php 7.4

Comment: I using Laravel 5.8 and the PHP version is 7.4

Comment: I am sure of this I just remembered I had this issue in the past.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228965/discussion-between-muresan-andrei-and-gerardo-marroquin).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in hosting server. In my localhost the PHP version was 8 and the default in hosting 7.4. I changed it to version 8 and the problem was fixed!